# PySpark: Converting config string items for dataframe operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

Input:

```
source_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
          (1,"1", "2020-01-01",10),
          (1,"2", "2020-01-01",20),
          (1,"2", "2020-02-01",30)
        ],
        ("country_code", "cust_id","day","value")
    )
```

Config:

```
input_config = """
                       [ {
                      "source":"source_dataframe",
                      "opearation":"max",
                      "group":["country_code", "cust_id"]
                        }
                       ]
                """

import json
config_dict = json.loads(input_config)
print(config_dict)
```

read from the config and apply operation on the input dataframe: Here I have hardcoded dataframe (source_dataframe) and operation (max).**this works fine**

```
for each in config_dict:
   result = source_dataframe.groupBy(["country_code", "cust_id"]).agg(max("value"))
result.show()
```

However instead of harcoding, if I try to read dataframe from config dynamically and apply the operation on input , I am running into different errors. This could be because, while reading they are converted as string. How do I convert the string object so that they work?

Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'groupBy'

```
result = each['source'].groupBy(["country_code", "cust_id"]).agg(max("value"))
```

Error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
result = source_dataframe.groupBy(["country_code", "cust_id"]).agg(each['opearation']("value"))
```

This section where I read groupBy dynamically works fine.

```
result = source_dataframe.groupBy(each["group"]).agg(max("value"))
```

tried looking other posts, but could not figure out a solution. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Following your example `each['source']` is `"source_dataframe"`, which is a string? JSON-decoding doesn't resolve strings into objects a variable with the same name as the string points to. You could try to use `globals()[each['source']]` instead of `each['source']`.

Comment: thanks @Timus. In gerenal, I was planning to keep all input dataframes in "source", (here to keep it simple I provided single source in json list in the config) which I can iterate and perform operations on dataframe. I understand while loading config using json method, it would consider them as string, hence the error. Is there any other ways to handle such usecases?

Comment: If the strings correspond to variables that point to dataframes you can try to access them via `globals()[each['source']]`. I.e., `globals()['source_dataframe']` should give you the corresponding dataframe. Depending on the structure of your progam `locals()` could also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should evaluate the string, which would grant you access to the underlying dataframe.

```
    result = eval(each['source']).groupBy(["country_code", cust_id"]).agg(max("value"))
```

Can't verify since i got an error from your first part.

Comment: thanks @N.dP , I tried using eval as well as globals() mentioned in above comment, both works. Can you help me understand how adding eval(each['source']) gives access to dataframe? On quick look, all evals() does it running a string as python code.

Comment: Yep, i dont have much to say that you already understood. each['source'] is a string that contains a variable assigned to a dataframe. Whereas eval(each['source']) will force python to run string contents as code, and then it will recognize the source_dataframe local variable. I use it mainly for complex merging conditions that i code as strings stored in a dedicated class of a unique script, then i call these conditions with eval(MyClass.desired_condition)